Everything is classified as background by segmentation model
I am training a U-NET model for medical image segmentation. Problem is that the binary masks that im using to train the model mostly consist of background pixels and a very small region of the whole image is the foreground, for example :\

Image

Corresponding Mask:


Consequently, my model is just predicting everything as background.
I have tried using three different loss functions - Dice Loss,Focal Loss and Focal Tvwersky Loss.
The Dice Loss and Focal Tvwersky Loss gave me high accuracies and high losses - close to 1, whereas Focal loss gave me high accuracies and low losses(around 0.01-0.08). Here are the loss functions I have tried using in the tensorflow model.fit method.
#Dice loss

def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred, smooth=1):
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)

def dice_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return 1 - dice_coef(y_true, y_pred)

#Focal tversky
ALPHA = 0.5
BETA = 0.5
GAMMA = 1

def FocalTverskyLoss(targets, inputs, alpha=ALPHA, beta=BETA, gamma=GAMMA, smooth=1e-6):

        #flatten label and prediction tensors
        inputs = K.flatten(inputs)
        targets = K.flatten(targets)

        #True Positives, False Positives & False Negatives
        TP = K.sum((inputs * targets))
        FP = K.sum(((1-targets) * inputs))
        FN = K.sum((targets * (1-inputs)))

        Tversky = (TP + smooth) / (TP + alpha*FP + beta*FN + smooth)
        FocalTversky = K.pow((1 - Tversky), gamma)

        return FocalTversky


ALPHA = 0.8
GAMMA = 2

def FocalLoss(targets, inputs, alpha=ALPHA, gamma=GAMMA):

    inputs = K.flatten(inputs)
    targets = K.flatten(targets)

    BCE = K.binary_crossentropy(targets, inputs)
    BCE_EXP = K.exp(-BCE)
    focal_loss = K.mean(alpha * K.pow((1-BCE_EXP), gamma) * BCE)

    return focal_loss

How should I approach the data or model training so it doesnt learn to always predict the background and thereby giving better predictions?

Your model is doing something, but not a lot. Because so many pixels in the training set are background pixels, it learns to predict mostly background pixels. There are many reasons why a model doesn't work, ranging from codebugs to problems with the data to more fundamental problems. I would not look at the loss function first, most likely you just don't have enough data or at least didn't train with enough data.
It can be a good idea to crop your images to only (or mostly) the part of the image of interest. This will speed up training as well as make it more effective.

Cropping the images helped , and im training on a much larger dataset now, hopefully it will give better results.
